# Overriding Manipulation Events on PivotItem

Tags: uwp, pivotitem

I have a UWP app where I am using a pivot control with a collection of pivot items. Now, my requirement is to capture the swipe down/up gestures on the pivot item. I have done something like below:

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Header="jdslj" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationStarted="UIElement_OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta"></PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="weew" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationStarted="UIElement_OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta"></PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="332" ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationStarted="UIElement_OnManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="UIElement_OnManipulationDelta"></PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Problem is, when I do it, it overrides the behaviour of pivot control and now I am not able to swipe left/right to change the pivot item.

Is there anything I can do to achieve both at the same time?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, your Manipulation can worked in the item body part of the `PivotItem`, but default "swiping left/right to change the pivot item" works on the header part of the `PivotItem`.

Comment: Pivot Item should change even if you swipe right/left on the 'item body'. I think if you remove the manipulation events then you would be able to see it.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! Sorry I didn't notice that.

Comment: Just tested again, Manipulation events here can cause your problem, but you can try to define your down/up gestures in the Pointer events, they can get fired and won't affect the default left/right gestures.

Comment: Could you throw some sample code please? It would be really helpful.

Comment: It is frustrating that I just found in this scenario seems only the UIElement.PointerMoved event, UIElement.PointerPressed event and UIElement.PointerEntered event can get fired on mobile. So the work can be done but not good, my sample handling the up/down guesture is not very sensitive.

Comment: Yeah. I am not sure how reliable these pointer based events are.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Can you post your sample please? I will try and see if it gets me to a starting point at least.

Answer (score 1):

As we've discussed, we can use the Pointer events to do this work, but only part of them work on mobile device in this scenario(on PC they work fine, you can have a try).

Here is my sample:

```xml
<Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Background="White" PointerPressed="Grid_PointerEntered"
      PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerMoved="Grid_PointerMoved">
    <Pivot x:Name="pivot">
        <PivotItem Header="jdslj">
            <TextBlock Name="textBlock" />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="weew">
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="332">
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

code behind:

```cs
private double Y;
private double deltaY;

private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootGrid);
    Y = pointer.Position.Y;
}

private void Grid_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var pointer = e.GetCurrentPoint(rootGrid);
    deltaY = pointer.Position.Y;
    if ((deltaY - Y) > 30)
    {
        textBlock.Text = "down";
        Y = 0;
        deltaY = 0;
    }
    else if ((Y - deltaY) > 30)
    {
        textBlock.Text = "up";
        Y = 0;
        deltaY = 0;
    }
}
```

Since you asked for a sample, I posted this answer, but I want to say again, my sample works, but not very sensitive.

Comment: I can see the problem you were talking about. So on mobile, PointerEnter/Pressed gets fired just fine but PointerMoved does not fire when I move my finger over the pivot item. It only gets fired if I move my finger on top of the grid (somewhere just above the pivot item).

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, yes, why you need up/down gestures? Can we use other event to implement this requirement?

Comment: So basically my pivot item is a calendar and it can have either week view or month view. Swiping up and down will actually change the view from month to week or week to month (based on the direction of swipe). It's like collapsing or expanding the control.

Comment: @AshishAgrawal, OK, maybe you can put a `TextBlock` in the title of pivot and use `Tapped` event to change the view from month to week or week to month? Like the default [CalendarDatePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.aspx)?

Comment: I am already doing that on tapping on the title. However, my requirement says that I need to support the swiping gesture as well. I am just a developer you know, who needs to stick to the design :D

Comment: yup. Thanks for the help :)